# discord.js 14 edit message/reply after button click

Tags: node.js, discord, embed, edit

I have a problem, I need to edit embed in message that contains button I clicked. I will post bellow my code. In confirm.js I tried to edit message like in the code, but I tried "interaction.editReply" etc. errors always like DiscordAPIError[10008]: Unknown Message.

PS: buttons basically works, but I'm struggling with editing message that contains the button

Any help?

// test command for message:

```js
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { embed_color } = require('../../../settings.json');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('test')
        .setDMPermission(true),

    execute(interaction) {
        const commandEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(embed_color)
            .setDescription('HAHAHA');

        const confirm = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('confirm')
            .setLabel('Confirm Ban')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

        const cancel = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('cancel')
            .setLabel('Cancel')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(cancel, confirm);

        interaction.reply({ 
            embeds: [commandEmbed],
            components: [row],
            ephemeral: true 
        });
    }
}
```

// button handler:

```js
function loadButtons(client) {
    const fs = require('fs');

    let buttonsList = [];

    fs.readdirSync("./src/buttons/").forEach(dir => {
        const buttonFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./src/buttons/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (let file of buttonFiles) {
            const button = require(`./buttons/${dir}/${file}`);

            client.buttons.set(button.data.name, button);

            buttonsList.push(button.data);
        }
    });

    return true;
}

module.exports = { loadButtons };
```

// executing buttons in on.interactionCreate

```js
if (interaction.isButton()) {
    
    const button = client.buttons.get(interaction.customId);

    if (button === undefined) {
        return interaction.reply({ 
            content: "This button is not supported, please inform developer!",
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }

    return button.execute(interaction, client);
}
```

// confirm button - the real deal, there I need to edit message and dunno how correctly

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: 'confirm'
    },

    async execute(interaction) {
        const commandEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(7646153)
            .setDescription('XD');

        console.log(interaction.message.embeds);
        interaction.message.edit({ embeds: [commandEmbed] });
    }
};
```

Comment: interaction function .update() works for people who will have the same problem. Thanks for ignoring me. Lock it or something, idc.